# How to copy a row of a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to copy element tree. In this process, I have to change some of the parameters like name, parameters being passed to some function assigned to the original element.
How can I set onclick and other method of an element.

For example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <select name="abc(0)" onclick="func(0)">
      <option> 1</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="keyp(0)" name="text(0)">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I tried various ways like cloneNode(true) and try to rename the nodes name and tried t change the methods parameters assigned. I also tried creating element by document.createElement but in IE, it is not changing the name. In the second option it is not even setting the name. Methods also are not getting changed, in second approach it was not even getting assigned.

Can someone please let me know where I am doing mistake.

Thanks & regards
Amit

Comment: I was not able to attach proper html, system was not allowing me to post the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: you can attach html if you mark it as code, as I have done.

Comment: thanks...now it seems better.

Comment: While editing, paste your code, select it by mouse, and prees `{}` symbol in editor's tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to get rid of the on_event_ attributes and refactor your javascript so it uses event listeners instead. That way the code that handles the events will be completely separate from the markup and cloning should not cause any problems.

Please note that you have to use delegated events since the event handlers will have to be called for cloned elements that don't exist on the page initially.

Comment: My biggest problem is I am not able to change the name of the element for case of IE. And event handlers I might need to learn a lot for that, as I am not aware much of them that how to make handler generic for any event anywhere. Are we saying we will make this handler work on document itself?

Comment: Got solution to the name part... We can use document.createElement('<select'+' name="'+name+'">')

Answer (score 0):

The only property you can't change in IE is the type for controls that have already been added to a form, you can change everything else. Note that in all browsers, cloned elements retain in-line listeners, as do elements with listeners added using *attachEvent* (which all libraries use for browsers that support *attachEvent* and not *addEventListener*).

The following snippet shows that the name property of a form element can be changed (tested in IE 8 standards mode) and that in-line listeners are retained for clonded nodes.

```
<form id="f0">
  <input type="text" name="inp0" onclick="alert(this.name);">
  <input type="button" value="Do clone" onclick="
    var el = this.form.inp0.cloneNode(true);
    this.form.appendChild(el);
    el.name = 'inp1';
  ">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the same. But onclick it gave me the desired output. But when I tried this: I found issue.      `<table> <tr><td>
  <select name="inp0" onclick="alert(this.name);"></select>
  <input type="button" value="Do clone" onclick="
    var el = getElement('inp0').parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    getElement('inp0').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(el);
    el.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].name = 'xyz'.replace('x','z');
    
    return false;
  "></td></tr></table>
<div onclick = "alert(getElement('inp0').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML)">here</div>`